# Gettin Bootstrap 3 Datepicker widget above everything else

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, z-index, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to get the widget to be above anything else (a map in my situation). See exemple : http://zoziologie.raphaelnussbaumer.com/improved-biolovision-visualisation/

I've try this without succes:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget{
    z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```

I'm using this datepicker: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was to have:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

I reshape my code using simple bootstrap grid instead of the bootstrap sidebar plugin and it worked!